# Saving a webpage for perl use

Tags: json, perl, html

I'm trying to save a webpage during one of my perl scripts, but currently I can't find a way to properly save or get its content.

The web page content is basically a json file.

I looked for the chrome command line option "--save-page-as-mhtml" but I couldn't find a way to pass him the save location.

Comment: Take a look at [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), or if the page requires JavaScript, [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox), [`WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS), or one of their buddies.

Comment: We need a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish. At a basic level `LWP` can fetch web pages and then you can dump the content to a file.

Comment: well, I need to get the content of a web page (which is a json file) into a variable in perl (array/hash of arrays/hashes).

I have the exact url of the location of that file. It's a request to an API in short. so it returns me a text file containing the information that I need.

Comment: I found my way with WWW::Mechanize. thanks ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Answer (score 2):

At a very basic level you can get a web page like this using [`LWP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm):

```
# Create a user agent object
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");

# Create a request
my $req = POST('http://search.cpan.org/search', [
   query => 'libwww-perl',
   mode  => 'dist',
]);

# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content;
}
else {
    die $res->status_line . "\n";
}
```

You can write `$res -> content` to a file easily enough, and that saves the JSON.

If it's JSON, you may find it useful to parse the JSON using the [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) library and potentially save the parsed JSON using [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html). (I'd generally suggest just saving the JSON as text and parsing it each time you load, but thought I'd offer `Storable` as it's quite a good way to turn an arbitrary perl data structure to an object on disk. )

Comment: Re "you may find it useful to parse the JSON using the JSON library and potentially save the parsed JSON using Storable.", I don't think any such person exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a command line program to download and save a web page then look at [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [lwp-request](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-request).